# sort dict and put the keys in an array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict which I want to sort by their values. After that I want the order of the keys to be put in an array. I tried some code, but all just output the values if It was sorted by the values or the keys if it was sorted by the keys. 
This is my dict:

```
{0: 1.0, 1: 22.0, 2: 30.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 17.0, 5: 9.0, 6: 13.0, 7: 21.0, 8: 
24.0, 9: 18.0, 10: 14.0, 11: 2.0, 12: 20.0, 13: 23.0, 14: 19.0, 15: 15.0, 16: 
6.0, 17: 26.0, 18: 11.0, 19: 5.0, 20: 29.0, 21: 7.0, 22: 12.0, 23: 27.0, 24: 
25.0, 25: 16.0, 26: 3.0, 27: 4.0, 28: 28.0, 29: 10.0}
```

It should return something like this:

```
[0,11,26,27,19,16, etc]
```

Comment: `sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get)` is all you need; it return `[0, 11, 26, 27, 19, 16, 21, 3, 5, 29, 18, 22, 6, 10, 15, 25, 4, 9, 14, 12, 7, 1, 13, 8, 24, 17, 23, 28, 20, 2]` for your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your dictionary `d`:

```
result = sorted(d, key=d.get)
```

`sorted(d)` without a `key` argument would iterate over the keys in `d` create a list from it and give it back with the natural sort order. (It iterates over keys because that is the normal iteration for a dictionary.) The `key` argument allows you to pass in a function that returns a proxy value to sort by for each item. After sorting the proxy values are discarded and you just get the items you wanted sorted. `key=d.get` uses the original dictionary to lookup the value associated with each item.

Comment: Thank you. this works. For my understanding, the d.get refers to the values of the dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
def get_keys_ordered_using_values(data):
    return list(map(lambda y: y[0], sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])))

my_data = {0: 1.0, 1: 22.0, 2: 30.0, 3: 8.0, 4: 17.0, 5: 9.0, 6: 13.0, 7: 21.0, 
           8: 24.0, 9: 18.0, 10: 14.0, 11: 2.0, 12: 20.0, 13: 23.0, 14: 19.0, 15: 15.0, 
        16: 6.0, 17: 26.0, 18: 11.0, 19: 5.0, 20: 29.0, 21: 7.0, 22: 12.0, 23: 27.0, 
        24: 25.0, 25: 16.0, 26: 3.0, 27: 4.0, 28: 28.0, 29: 10.0}

print(get_keys_ordered_using_values(my_data))
```